# Setting a global scope variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scope, onload

I'm trying to setup animation triggers based on the height of the element. The project is built with AngularJS, but the problem I'm having seems really bizzare. I'm trying to set an imgH variable when the image loads. Inside my onload function the log returns the correct image height and sets the global variable imgH. After my onload function the console log command returns imgH = undefined

```
var imgH;
        $('.step-image').on('load',function(){
            imgH = $(this).height();
            console.log(imgH);
        });
console.log(imgH);
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of async! the `load` event is happening *after* the `console.log` at the end of your code, so at that point the `imgH` value is not set.

Comment: "You are phoning for a pizza, then trying to eat the pizza before it is delivered" :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I was going to use it :D

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Surprised you do not have it on a shortcut key :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: No, not mine (hence the quote). I saw it on SO in the last week or so. It works so well at getting the idea across that I started using it to explain the concept myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable *is* getting set, it's just not *yet* set when you do that `console.log` at the end.

Here's the sequence in which your code runs:

1. `var imgH;` - Creates the global with an initial value of `undefined`.
2. `$('.step-image').on('load', function ...)` - Sets up the handler, doesn't (yet) call the function.
3. `console.log(imgH);` (at the bottom) - Shows `undefined` because nothing has assigned a value to `imgH` yet.
4. **Later**, when the image loads, the handler function is called and sets `imgH`.
5. `console.log(imgH);` (inside the handler function) - Shows the value.